# Vim: a weird background problem in gnome-terminal

Tags: linux, linux-ubuntu

[image: Weird border]

I get weird border form gnome-terminal when i run Vim fullscreen. It never
happened before. I'm confused. How to repair it without changing my terminal 
background colour?

Comment: What's the weird part?

Comment: I guess you talk about the white border. This border seems to be drawn by the terminal. What happens if you maximize the terminal without a running Vim?

Comment: Today I worked in full screen in gnome-terminal (F11) and I realized i also have this border. I just didn't see it as it is black. I  realized it because there was a small gap to the right of the status bar. This gap changes depending on the font size (Ctrl-+, Ctrl--). I assume that the width of the fullscreen terminal is not dividable by the pixel-width per character cell. So some pixels are left unused. The same for height. I don't know how to prove this.